# get additional info from the link which launched my app

Tags: android

my app launches on clicking a link.

But there is additional information that the link contains which my app wants.

The link is something like this :

http://update_app_config.com?parameter1='value1'&parameter2='value2'&parameter3='value3'

can I get an object of key,value pair which contains the parameter and values or do I have to parse it myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getIntent().getUri()` will return a `Uri` object representing the link used to launch your app. You can then call methods like `getQueryParameterNames()` and `getQueryParameters()` to access the query parameters (stuff to the right of the ?).

Comment: Thanks. But when I use getIntent().getUri(), I get null.

Comment: @user1692808: That is strange. You are calling this from the activity whose `<intent-filter>` matched the URL, right? Here is a sample app demonstrating this: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/URLHandler